# .latexmkrc for bib2gls

Tags: compiling, latexmk, bib2gls

I'm trying to set up a `.latexmkrc` file, to compile the document I'm creating and call both `biber` and `bib2gls`, but I'm having a problem: sometimes the rule for calling `bib2gls` works (by registering the rule and informing about the action), but sometimes it won't.

Here is my `.latexmkrc`:

```
add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'run_makeglossaries');
add_cus_dep('acn', 'acr', 0, 'run_makeglossaries');

add_cus_dep('aux', 'glstex', 0, 'run_bib2gls');

sub run_makeglossaries {
  if ( $silent ) {
    system "makeglossaries -q '$_[0]'";
  } else {
    system "makeglossaries '$_[0]'";
  };
}

sub run_bib2gls {
  if ( $silent ) {
    system "bib2gls --silent --group '$_[0]'";
  } else {
    system "bib2gls --group '$_[0]'";
  };
}

push @generated_exts, 'glo', 'gls', 'glg';
push @generated_exts, 'acn', 'acr', 'alg';
$clean_ext .= ' %R.ist %R.xdy';
$clean_ext .= ' bbl run.xml'
```

As far as I understand, the `add_cus_dep` procedure links the desired input extension of a file with the desired output one, using the provided function name to do the conversion.

Is something in my code (regarding `run_bib2gls`) wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't there be some dependence on the `.bib` file?

Comment: @AndrewSwann The `.bib` file may not have the same base name as the `.tex` file (and there may be `.bib` files for `bibtex` or `biblatex`). The rule to run `bib2gls` is essentially: if the `.aux` file contains `\glsxtr@resource` and the `.glstex` file is older than the `.aux` file then run `bib2gls`. I don't know how `latexmk` deals with that kind of rule.

Comment: So I guess one needs to do same parsing of the `.aux` file to extract the `.bib` file name(s) from the `\glsxtr@resource` commands.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Yes and there may be multiple `\glsxtr@resource{options}{base}` commands within the `.aux` file. The second argument is the base name of the corresponding `.glstex` file. If `src` is omitted from `options` then the `.bib` file has the same base name. So `\glsxtr@resource{}{sample}` means `bib2gls` should create a file called `sample.glstex` using information in `sample.bib` whereas `\glsxtr@resource{src={file1,file2}}{sample}` means `bib2gls` should create a file called `sample.glstex` using information in `file1.bib` and `file2.bib`.

Answer (score 5):

There are actually two issues to solve:

1. There's a problem with `latexmk` so that it fails to call `bib2gls` if the `.glstex` file doesn't exist; this is the situation where the `.glstex` file needs to be created from scratch. The problem is `latexmk` doesn't recognize the message in the `.log` file about a missing file.  (The message isn't in one of the formats programmed into `latexmk`.)  I will fix this in the next release. Meanwhile, insert the following line in your `.latexmkrc` file:

   ```
   push @file_not_found, '^Package .* No file `([^\\\']*)\\\'';
   ```
2. Changes in the `.bib` file don't get noticed by `latexmk` as reasons to rerun `bib2gls`.  To solve this, the log file from `bib2gls` needs to be analyzed to find the name of the `bib` file, and then this needs to be set as a dependent.  This is done by the following extension of your `run_bib2gls` subroutine:

   ```
   sub run_bib2gls {
     if ( $silent ) {
       my $ret = system "bib2gls --silent --group '$_[0]'";
     } else {
       my $ret = system "bib2gls --group '$_[0]'";
     };
     my ($base, $path) = fileparse( $_[0] );
     if ($path && -e "$base.glstex") {
       rename "$base.glstex", "$path$base.glstex";
     }
     # Analyze log file.
     local *LOG;
     $LOG = "$_[0].glg";
     if (!$ret && -e $LOG) {
       open LOG, "<$LOG";
       while (<LOG>) {
         if (/^Reading (.*\.bib)\s$/) {
           rdb_ensure_file( $rule, $1 );
         }
       }
       close LOG;
     }
     return $ret;
   }
   ```

This code also handles the case that an output directory is specified.

@NicolaTalbot: Yes, I do know about the `-d` option to `bib2gls`, but when I tried it, there were problems: On the second and subsequent calls to `bib2gls` from within `latexmk`, `bib2gls` tries to write the `.glstex` to the wrong directory.  Unfortunately I haven't yet tracked down what was going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite old now, but in case anyone else needs this. The following code snippet will correctly (I hope) use the `-d` switch for `bib2gls`.

```
sub run_bib2gls {
  my ($base, $path) = fileparse( $_[0] );
  my $silent_command = $silent ? "--silent" : "";
  if ( $path ) {
    my $ret = system("bib2gls $silent_command -d '$path' --group '$base'");
  } else {
    my $ret = system("bib2gls $silent_command --group '$_[0]'");
  };
  # Analyze log file.
  local *LOG;
  $LOG = "$_[0].glg";
  if (!$ret && -e $LOG) {
    open LOG, "<$LOG";
    while (<LOG>) {
      if (/^Reading (.*\.bib)\s$/) {
        rdb_ensure_file( $rule, $1 );
      }
    }
    close LOG;
  }
  return $ret;
}
```