# Glossaries Dual Entry IsUsed Flag

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

So I have this macro to be used with the `glossaries` package:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\newdualentry}{ O{} O{} m m m m } {
    \newglossaryentry{gls-#3}{name={#5 (#4)},description={#6},#1}
    \newglossaryentry{#3}{type=\acronymtype, name={#4}, description=#5, first={\gls{gls-#3}}, see=[Glossar:]{gls-#3}}
}
```

This allows me to define dual entries like this:

```
\newdualentry{CAE} % label
{CAE}            % abbreviation
{Computer Aided Engineering}  % long form
{Zu Deutsch rechnergestützte Entwicklung. In der Automobilbranche häufig als Dachbegriff für alle Berechnungsaufgaben, wie FEM-Berechnungen oder Strömungsberechnungen gesehen} % description
```

But now the problem: When I don't reference this entry in the document and do

```
\printacronyms
```

All the entries will still be displayed nevertheless.

How can I stop this from happening?

I've tried adding `\glsunset{#3}` and `\glsunset{gls-#3}` to the `\newdualentry` command but without success.

EDIT: Add compilable example

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
% !TEX spellcheck = de_DE
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,numbers=enddot,bibliography=totoc,toc=sectionentrywithdots,dvipsnames]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Formatting
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Europäische fontcodierung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Deutsch
\usepackage{textcomp} % Euro Zeichen usw für T1 font
\usepackage{lmodern} %Clear PDF Fonts

\usepackage[
    %hidelinks,
    pdfborder={0 0 0},
    bookmarks,
    linktoc=all,
    bookmarksopen=true,
    colorlinks=false,
    linkcolor=blue, % einfache interne Verkn¸pfungen
    anchorcolor=black, % Ankertext
    citecolor=red, % Verweise auf Literaturverzeichniseintr‰ge im Text
    filecolor=black, % Verkn¸pfungen, die lokale Dateien ˆffnen
    menucolor=black, % Acrobat-Men¸punkte
    urlcolor=blue, 
    pagebackref=false,
    plainpages=false, % zur korrekten Erstellung der Bookmarks
    pdfpagelabels, % zur korrekten Erstellung der Bookmarks
    %hypertexnames=false, % zur korrekten Erstellung der Bookmarks
]{hyperref}


%------------------------ Glossaries ----------------------
\usepackage[acronyms,translate=babel,xindy,style=list]{glossaries}


\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\newdualentry}{ O{} O{} m m m m } {
    \glsunsetall
    \newglossaryentry{gls-#3}{name={#5 (#4)},description={#6},#1}
    \newglossaryentry{#3}{type=\acronymtype, name={#4}, description=#5, first={\gls{gls-#3}}, see=[Glossar:]{gls-#3}}
}


%----------------------- First Gls Entry Format --------------------------

    % First GLs with Footnote
\defglsentryfmt{%
    \glsifplural{
        \ifglsused{\glslabel}{%
            \unskip\textit{\glsentryplural{\glslabel}}\ignorespaces%
        }{%
            % Typeset first use
            \unskip\textit{\glsentryplural{\glslabel}}\footnote{\Glsentrydesc{\glslabel}.}\ignorespaces%
        }%
    }{
        \ifglsused{\glslabel}{%
            \unskip\textit{\glsgenentryfmt}\ignorespaces%
        }{%
            % Typeset first use
            \unskip\textit{\glsentryname{\glslabel}}\footnote{\Glsentrydesc{\glslabel}.}\ignorespaces%
        }%
    }
}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeglossaries

%----------------------- GLS Definitions --------------------------
\newdualentry{FEM} % label
{FEM}            % abbreviation
{Finite Elemente Methode}  % long form
{Numerisches Berechnungsverfahren, um Spannungen und Kräfte in und zwischen Bauteilen zu ermitteln} % description

\newdualentry{CAD} % label
{CAD}            % abbreviation
{Computer Aided Design}  % long form
{Zu Deutsch rechnerunterstütztes Konstruieren. Das computergestützte erstellen von 3D-Modellen} % description

\newacronym{PKW}{PKW}{Personenkraftwagen}

%------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
    \printacronyms
    \printglossary

    \newpage
    \section{Tester}
    TestTest \gls{CAD}

\end{document}
```

Notice how the Glossaries list is correct but not the Acronyms list.

Comment: Since you have not posted a compilable document but fragments only, I can only suspect that `\gls` inside  the acronym definition (the second usage of `\newglossaryentry` within `\newdualentry` triggers the usage counter. You should not use `\gls` inside `\newglossaryentry` to avoid nested linking. I am wondering about `\makeglossaries` inside your command.

Comment: 'Off-topic': Please go through list of questions and consider to accept answers that were given to them in order to appreciate the work done here by users

Comment: ah sorry i forgot to mention the problem also occurs when the description is Text only. I'll add a compilable sample.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer without the '\makeglossaries' the document doesn't compile.

Comment: The `\makeglossaries` should be done before `\newglossaryentries``

Comment: Well according to https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Glossary
It's needed. Damn you're so fast. I'll edit the sample above.

Comment: Why do you think wikibooks is correct? Anybody can screw up the text there. Read the manual, you will find `\makeglossaries` **before** `\newglossaryentries`

Comment: Alright, I'm reading the Documentation right now. And I've edited the Code sample above. The original Problem still occurs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I think it looks a bit redundant to have entries in the form

> CAD Computer Aided Design. 2, *Glossar:* Computer Aided Design (CAD)

The repetition looks awkward, and why make the reader look up a reference in one list only to be redirected to another? However, I know it's commonly done (and there's a similar example in the `glossaries` user manual), so here's an explanation of the problem and how to circumvent it.

> I've tried adding `\glsunset{#3}` and `\glsunset{gls-#3}` to the
>   `\newdualentry` command but without success.

The first use flag doesn't govern whether an entry appears in a glossary, so `\glsunset` won't affect it. It's the indexing function that adds the entry to the index.

The `see` key automatically indexes the entry when it's defined. This behaviour is [documented in the manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:newglosentry):

> Using the `see` key will *automatically add this entry to the glossary*,
>   but will not automatically add the cross-referenced entry. The
>   referenced entry should be supplied as the value to this key.

This can be illustrated with a much simpler MWE, but it's the same basic problem you have with yours:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{foo}{name={foo},description={foo description}}
\newglossaryentry{bar}{name={bar},description={bar description},see={foo}}

\begin{document}
\gls{foo}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Even though `bar` isn't referenced in the document it appears in the glossary because of the `see` key.

If you want to use the `see` key for an entry that may not be referenced in the document, there are three main approaches.

### Method 1: Don't Use `see` Key

Instead of using the `see` key, add `\glssee` to the description:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{foo}{name={foo},description={foo description}}
\newglossaryentry{bar}{name={bar},description={bar description\glssee{bar}{foo}}}

\begin{document}
\gls{foo}, \gls{bar}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

The cross-reference won't be performed until the glossary has been created, so if the document is called, say, `myDoc.tex` then the build process is:

```
pdflatex myDoc
makeglossaries myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
makeglossaries myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

(Replace `pdflatex` with `xelatex` etc as appropriate.)

### General Comments

- As Christian mentioned in the comments, the use of `\gls` inside fields causes [nested links](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#sec:nested), which are problematic.
- Your code has spurious spaces in it caused by end of line characters, which you've compensated for using `\unskip` and `\ignorespaces`. It's simpler just to comment out the spurious spaces:

  ```
  \defglsentryfmt{%
      \glsifplural{% <---- added
          \ifglsused{\glslabel}{%
              \textit{\glsentryplural{\glslabel}}%
          }{%
              % Typeset first use
              \textit{\glsentryplural{\glslabel}}\footnote{\Glsentrydesc{\glslabel}.}%
          }%
      }{% <---- added
          \ifglsused{\glslabel}{%
              \textit{\glsgenentryfmt}%
          }{%
              % Typeset first use
              \textit{\glsentryname{\glslabel}}\footnote{\Glsentrydesc{\glslabel}.}%
          }%
      }% <---- added
  }
  ```
- Your entry format code also doesn't check for case changes or custom text so you will have unexpected results if you use `\glsdisp` or `\glslink` or `\GLS` etc.

### Method 2: Disable automatic indexing

If you define entries before the relevant glossary files have been opened (that is, before `\makeglossaries`) then indexing can't occur at that point. Since this can happen accidentally, the `glossaries` package by default raises an error. So modifying the above:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{foo}{name={foo},description={foo description}}
\newglossaryentry{bar}{name={bar},description={bar description},see={foo}}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\gls{foo}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This causes the error message:

```
! Package glossaries Error: `see' key may only be used after \makeglossaries or
 \makenoidxglossaries (or move \newglossaryentry definitions into the preamble)
```

(This is the reason why the general advice is to put `\makeglossaries` before `\newglossaryentry`, `\newacronym` etc as mentioned in the comments.)

You can prevent this error message with `seenoindex=ignore`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[seenoindex=ignore]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{foo}{name={foo},description={foo description}}
\newglossaryentry{bar}{name={bar},description={bar description},see={foo}}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\gls{foo}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Now only `foo` appears in the glossary because the `see` key in `bar` silently fails. However if you later index `bar`, you don't get the cross-reference:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[seenoindex=ignore]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{foo}{name={foo},description={foo description}}
\newglossaryentry{bar}{name={bar},description={bar description},see={foo}}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\gls{foo}, \gls{bar}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

The base `glossaries` package doesn't store the value of the `see` key, but the extension package [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) does and it also has an option to prevent the auto-indexing (`autoseeindex=false`). You can then iterate over all used entries at the end of the document and check for the presence of the `see` field:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[autoseeindex=false]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{foo}{name={foo},description={foo description}}
\newglossaryentry{bar}{name={bar},description={bar description},see={foo}}

\newcommand{\seeref}[1][\seename]{\def\dosee{\glssee[#1]}\xseeref}
\def\xseeref#1|#2|{\dosee{#2}{#1}}
\AtEndDocument
{%
  \forallglossaries{\thistype}%
  {%
    \forglsentries[\thistype]{\thislabel}%
    {%
      \ifglsused{\thislabel}%
      {%
         \ifglshasfield{see}{\thislabel}%
         {\expandafter\seeref\glscurrentfieldvalue|\thislabel|}{}%
      }%
      {}%
    }%
  }
}

\begin{document}
\gls{foo}, \gls{bar}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

The document build is simpler than in the first method:

```
pdflatex myDoc
makeglossaries myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

Note that with `glossaries-extra` you need to set the abbreviation style using `\setabbreviationstyle`. For example:

```
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\newacronym{PKW}{PKW}{Personenkraftwagen}
```

or

```
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}
\newabbreviation{PKW}{PKW}{Personenkraftwagen}
```

Returning to your MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,autoseeindex=false]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\newdualentry}{ O{} O{} m m m m }{%
  \newglossaryentry{gls-#3}{name={#5 (#4)},description={#6},#1}%
  \newacronym[see={gls-#3},#2]{#3}{#4}{#5}%
}

\apptoglossarypreamble[acronym]{\renewcommand{\seename}{Glossar:}}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\renewcommand{\glsfirstlongdefaultfont}[1]{\emph{#1}}
\renewcommand{\glsfirstabbrvdefaultfont}[1]{\emph{#1}}

\newcommand{\glsxtrpostlinkacronym}{%
 \ifglsentryexists{gls-\glslabel}%
 {%
   \glsadd{gls-\glslabel}%
   \glsxtrifwasfirstuse
   {%
     \footnote{\Glsentrydesc{gls-\glslabel}}%
   }%
   {}%
 }%
 {}%
}

\newdualentry{FEM} % label
{FEM}            % abbreviation
{Finite Elemente Methode}  % long form
{Numerisches Berechnungsverfahren, um Spannungen und Kräfte in und
zwischen Bauteilen zu ermitteln} % description

\newdualentry{CAD} % label
{CAD}            % abbreviation
{Computer Aided Design}  % long form
{Zu Deutsch rechnerunterstütztes Konstruieren. Das computergestützte
erstellen von 3D-Modellen} % description

\newacronym{PKW}{PKW}{Personenkraftwagen}

\newcommand{\seeref}[1][\seename]{\def\dosee{\glssee[#1]}\xseeref}
\def\xseeref#1|#2|{\dosee{#2}{#1}}
\AtEndDocument
{%
  \forallglossaries{\thistype}%
  {%
    \forglsentries[\thistype]{\thislabel}%
    {%
      \ifglsused{\thislabel}%
      {%
         \ifglshasfield{see}{\thislabel}%
         {\expandafter\seeref\glscurrentfieldvalue|\thislabel|}{}%
      }%
      {}%
    }%
  }
}

\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=acronym]
\printglossary

\newpage
\section{Tester}
Test \gls{CAD}.

Test \gls{CAD}.

Test \gls{FEM}.

Test \gls{PKW}.

\end{document}
```

Page 1:

[image: image of page 1]

Top of page 2:

[image: image of page 2]

Bottom of page 2:

[image: image of page 2 footnotes]

### Method 3: Use `bib2gls`

The problem doesn't occur if you use `bib2gls`, but entries need to be defined in a `.bib` file. A regular entry can be defined using `@entry`. For example:

```
@entry{foo,
  name={foo},
  description={foo description}
}
```

An abbreviation can be defined using `@abbreviation`. For example:

```
@abbreviation{PKW,
   short={PKW},
   long={Personenkraftwagen}
}
```

A dual entry and abbreviation can be defined using `@dualabbreviationentry`:

```
@dualabbreviationentry{FEM,
  short={FEM},
  long = {Finite Elemente Methode},
  description = {Numerisches Berechnungsverfahren, um Spannungen und Kräfte in und zwischen Bauteilen zu ermitteln}
}
```

So create a file called, say, `abbreviations.bib` that contains:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@dualabbreviationentry{FEM,
  short = {FEM},
  long  = {Finite Elemente Methode},
  description = {Numerisches Berechnungsverfahren, 
   um Spannungen und Kräfte in und zwischen Bauteilen zu ermitteln},
  see={[Glossar:]dual.FEM}
}

@dualabbreviationentry{CAD,
  short = {CAD},
  long = {Computer Aided Design},
  description = {Zu Deutsch rechnerunterstütztes Konstruieren. Das
  computergestützte erstellen von 3D-Modellen},
  see={[Glossar:]dual.FEM}
}

@abbreviation{PKW,
  short = {PKW},
  long = {Personenkraftwagen}
}
```

The (simplified) document is:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[record,% use bib2gls
 abbreviations,% create list of abbreviations
 nostyles,% only need list style so don't load others
 stylemods={list},% load glossary-list.sty
 style=list]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources
[ 
  src = {abbreviations} % entry definitions in abbreviations.bib
]

\begin{document}
\printunsrtglossary[type=abbreviations]
\printunsrtglossary

\newpage
\section{Tester}
Test \gls{CAD}.

Test \gls{CAD}.

\end{document}
```

The document build is:

```
pdflatex myDoc
bib2gls myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

This doesn't quite match as it duplicates the `see` field in both entries:

[image: image of list of abbreviations and list of terms]

A better approach is to omit the `see` field and adjust the style to check for the dual entry. This makes the code more flexible. The `@dual...` entry types are linked by `bib2gls` so if you index one in the document the other is automatically selected as well. The label for the linked entry can be saved using `dual-field`.

The `abbreviations.bib` file now looks like:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@dualabbreviationentry{FEM,
  short = {FEM},
  long  = {Finite Elemente Methode},
  description = {Numerisches Berechnungsverfahren, 
   um Spannungen und Kräfte in und zwischen Bauteilen zu ermitteln}
}

@dualabbreviationentry{CAD,
  short = {CAD},
  long = {Computer Aided Design},
  description = {Zu Deutsch rechnerunterstütztes Konstruieren. Das
  computergestützte erstellen von 3D-Modellen}
}

@abbreviation{PKW,
  short = {PKW},
  long = {Personenkraftwagen}
}
```

The document is now:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[record,% use bib2gls
 abbreviations,% create list of abbreviations
 nostyles,% only need list style so don't load others
 stylemods={list},% load glossary-list.sty
 style=list]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources
[
  src = {abbreviations}, % entry definitions in abbreviations.bib
  dual-field={dualid}% save label of dual entry in this field
]

\newcommand{\glsxtrpostnamegeneral}{%
  \ifglshasfield{dualid}{\glscurrententrylabel}%
  { (\glshyperlink{\glscurrentfieldvalue})}%
  {}%
}

\renewcommand{\glsxtrpostdescabbreviation}{%
  \ifglshasfield{dualid}{\glscurrententrylabel}%
  { (\textit{Glossar:} 
     \glshyperlink[\glsentryname\glscurrentfieldvalue]{\glscurrentfieldvalue})}%
  {}%
}

\begin{document}
\printunsrtglossary[type=abbreviations]
\printunsrtglossary

\newpage
\section{Tester}
Test \gls{CAD}.

Test \gls{CAD}.

\end{document}
```

This provides a link (shown by the red rectangle below) from an entry in one list to the corresponding one in the other:

[image: image of list of abbreviations and glossary]

Alternatively, you can make the description a hyperlink to remove the repetition:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[record,% use bib2gls
 abbreviations,% create list of abbreviations
 postdot,% add full stop (period) after description
 nostyles,% only need list style so don't load others
 stylemods={list},% load glossary-list.sty
 style=list]{glossaries-extra}

\newcommand{\bibglsnewdualabbreviationentry}[5]{%
  \newabbreviation
  [#2,description={\bibglshyperlink{#4}{\glsxtrusefield{#1}{dualid}}}]
  {#1}{#3}{#4}%
}

\GlsXtrLoadResources
[
  src = {abbreviations}, % entry definitions in abbreviations.bib
  dual-field={dualid},% save label of dual entry in this field
  dual-backlink
]

\newcommand{\glsxtrpostnamegeneral}{%
  \ifglshasfield{dualid}{\glscurrententrylabel}%
  { (\glshyperlink{\glscurrentfieldvalue})}%
  {}%
}

\begin{document}
\printunsrtglossary[type=abbreviations]
\printunsrtglossary

\newpage
\section{Tester}
Test \gls{CAD}.

Test \gls{CAD}.

\end{document}
```

[image: image of list of abbreviations and glossary]

The document above references the *primary* entry (`\gls{CAD}`), which is the abbreviation, so the location only appears in the list of abbreviations, the "2" after "Computer Aided Design" in:

> **Akronyme**
>
> **CAD** Computer Aided Design. 2
>
> **Glossar**
>
> **Computer Aided Design (CAD)** Zu Deutsch rechnerunterstütztes Konstruieren. Das computergestützte erstellen von 3D-Modellen.

You can remove it completely with `save-locations=false`:

```
\GlsXtrLoadResources
[
  src = {abbreviations}, % entry definitions in abbreviations.bib
  dual-field={dualid},% save label of dual entry in this field
  dual-backlink,
  save-locations=false
]
```

Or you can combine the locations with `combine-dual-locations=both` so that both the list of abbreviations and the glossary show the same location lists:

```
\GlsXtrLoadResources
[
  src = {abbreviations}, % entry definitions in abbreviations.bib
  dual-field={dualid},% save label of dual entry in this field
  dual-backlink,
  combine-dual-locations=both
]
```

Or you can use `combine-dual-locations=dual` to move all locations to the dual list (the glossary) or use `combine-dual-locations=primary` to move all locations to the primary list (the list of abbreviations).

The abbreviation style can be modified to append the description obtained from the dual entry:

```
\newcommand{\glsxtrpostlinkabbreviation}{%
 \glsxtrifwasfirstuse
 {%
   \ifglshasfield{dualid}{\glslabel}%
   {\footnote{\glsentrydesc{\glscurrentfieldvalue}}}%
   {}%
 }%
 {}%
}
```

You can make the long and short form italic on first use with:

```
\renewcommand{\glsfirstlongdefaultfont}[1]{\emph{#1}}
\renewcommand{\glsfirstabbrvdefaultfont}[1]{\emph{#1}}
```

The abbreviation styles should always be set before `\GlsXtrLoadResources`

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[record,% use bib2gls
 abbreviations,% create list of abbreviations
 postdot,% add full stop (period) after description
 nostyles,% only need list style so don't load others
 stylemods={list},% load glossary-list.sty
 style=list]{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}

\newcommand{\glsxtrpostlinkabbreviation}{%
 \glsxtrifwasfirstuse
 {%
   \ifglshasfield{dualid}{\glslabel}%
   {\footnote{\glsentrydesc{\glscurrentfieldvalue}}}%
   {}%
 }%
 {}%
}

\renewcommand{\glsfirstlongdefaultfont}[1]{\emph{#1}}
\renewcommand{\glsfirstabbrvdefaultfont}[1]{\emph{#1}}

\newcommand{\bibglsnewdualabbreviationentry}[5]{%
  \newabbreviation
  [#2,description={\bibglshyperlink{#4}{\glsxtrusefield{#1}{dualid}}}]
  {#1}{#3}{#4}%
}

\GlsXtrLoadResources
[
  src = {abbreviations}, % entry definitions in abbreviations.bib
  dual-field={dualid},% save label of dual entry in this field
  dual-backlink
]

\newcommand{\glsxtrpostnamegeneral}{%
  \ifglshasfield{dualid}{\glscurrententrylabel}%
  { (\glshyperlink{\glscurrentfieldvalue})}%
  {}%
}

\begin{document}
\printunsrtglossary[type=abbreviations]
\printunsrtglossary

\newpage
\section{Tester}
Test \gls{CAD}.

Test \gls{CAD}.

\end{document}
```

[image: image of page 1]

[image: image of page 2]

Comment: Oh my, a very elaborate answer!!!! ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I thought this had already come up before but I couldn't find it (just vaguely related questions).

Comment: Okay, the `bib2gls` option seems to do exactly what I want. But there are drawbacks. It doesn't seem to handle german umlauts like _äüö_. 
The others aren't as bad though. Filenames with spaces don't seem to work and I couldn't figure out how to get `bib2gls` working with Latexmk. I found a sample `latexmkrc` in the source but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: And Method 2 doesn't crash with umlauts but it weirdly just doesn't print them.

Comment: @JoshK `bib2gls` should handle umlauts. Check the file encoding. The `% Encoding: UTF-8` comment line needs to match the `.bib` file encoding. You can explicitly set the `.bib` file encoding using the resource option `charset=UTF-8` and the `.tex` encoding with `--tex-encoding`. By default sorting should be done according to the document language, which for `ngerman` should be equivalent to `sort=de-1996`. I'll check the filenames with spaces. I don't use `latexmk` but there's a [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400325) which is currently unresolved.

Comment: @JoshK I didn't add `inputenc` to the example in method 2. It should work if it's added.

Comment: Aaah oh I missed that. Yes, now it works. 
I've added the `dualentry` part to Method 2 along with your corrected version for the footnote on the first occasion. 
Sadly it doesn't do the footnote when referencing the `dualentry`