# concitional compilation of bib2gls with arara

Tags: arara, bib2gls

I'm working on a large project (3 volumes of about 500 pages each), and I'm using `bib2gls` to manage my glossaries. In order to save compilation time I started using `arara` with conditionals like in [How to tell Arara to skip redundant steps?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489562/how-to-tell-arara-to-skip-redundant-steps) but I cannot figure out how to pass a conditional to run `bib2gls` only when I add another instance of a glossary entry in my document, say `\gls{example}`.

I've tried adding `% arara: bib2gls if changed ('glg') || changed ('glstex')` assuming that I've made a previous run so that both `MyDoc.glg` and `MyDoc.glstex` already exists. I don't understand how `bib2gls` works but I noticed that `MyDoc.glstex` changes by adding the `example` information after running `bib2gls`. So I'm lost here.

I would appreciate any ideas or insight about `bib2gls` to solve my problem.

---

### Edit: a MWE

`MyDoc.tex`:

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: biber if missing('bbl') || found('log', 'Citation')
% arara: --> || changed (toFile('MyBibliography.bib'))
% arara: bib2gls if missing('glstex') || changed ('glg') 
% arara: --> || changed ('glstex') || changed (toFile('MyGlos.bib'))
% arara: xelatex until !found('log', '\\(?(R|r)e\\)?run (to get|LaTeX)')

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[record,index,postdot]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{glossary-bookindex}

\setglossarystyle{bookindex}
\renewcommand{\glsxtrbookindexcols}{3}
\newglossary{ind}{ing}{ige}{My Index}
\GlsXtrLoadResources[
 src=MyGloss,
 type=ind,
]

\addbibresource{MyBibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

Test \gls{hi} as seen in~\cite{blah}

\printunsrtglossary[type=ind, style=bookindex]

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

`MyGloss.bib`:

```
@index{hi,
    name = {Hello World!},
}

@index{foo,
    name = {Foo},
}
```

`MyBlibliography.bib`:

```
@book{blah,
    author = {The Author},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    title = {An imortant book},
    year = {2020}
}
```

Finally, my first run:
[image]
And my second run:[image]

Comment: Please add an MWE to allow testing for anybody. I thnk that `arara` cant do this, because after first LaTeX run there are no `bi2gls` files. Best way would be to use `latexmk` via `arara` and setup `latexmk` in such a way to detect if it is needed to run `bib2gls` or not. I am not proficient with `latexmk`, so I dont know how to do that - but `latexmk` is scanning `.aux` file for clues, which is exactly what you are asking to do.

Comment: @TomášKruliš Thanks for the comment, I added a MWE and I'll start reading about `latexmk`

Comment: It seems to me that `bib2gls` always writes `.glstex` and `.glg` files. I guess that `latexmk` could be suitable to control this.

Comment: An elaboration of how to use `bib2gls` with `latexmk` should be here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400325/latexmkrc-for-bib2gls The issue is not very old (so theres big chance it will work without making changes) but the code looks pretty advanced (to me at least).

Comment: I’ll start working with that file, thanks for you comments